# any better solution to get duplicates and there count in an array?

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

I have the below code which is aimed at finding out a duplicate element in an array and printing it with its count.

I have used the below approach to solve the problem.

1. copy the original array into temp array
2. find the duplicates in original array and remove the same
3. copy the non duplicate array into another temp array
4. compare non duplicate array with original array and print out the duplicates with their counts.

For calculating the length I am using my own version of code.

It o/ps 
5 4
2 3

which is correct but I want to know if we can still refine this code.

Please suggest best approach, condition is that there should not be any build in method/functions usage.

```
package codingpractice;

public class DuplicateCount {
public static void main(String argsp[]) throws Exception {
    int array[] = { 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5 };
    DuplicateCount hw = new DuplicateCount();
    int length = hw.length(array);
    hw.duplicates(array, length);
}

public void duplicates(int array[], int length) throws Exception {

    int end =length, dupCount = 0;

    //copying to another array for later comparison
    int[] aarray = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        aarray[i] = array[i];
    }

    //finding duplicates and removing the same
    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                int shiftLeft = j;
                for (int k = j + 1; k < end; k++, shiftLeft++) {
                    array[shiftLeft] = array[k];
                }
                end--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    //copying non duplicates to another array
    int[] tarray = new int[end];
    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        tarray[i] = array[i];

    }

    //Printing duplicates and there counts, comparing original array and non     duplicate array
    for (int i = 0; i < length(tarray); i++) {
        dupCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (tarray[i] == aarray[j]) {
                dupCount++;
            }
        }
        if (dupCount > 1) {
            System.out.println(tarray[i] + " " + dupCount);
        }
    }
}

//length of array- not using inbuild function
int length(int array[]) throws Exception {
    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            count++;
            temp = array[count];
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return count;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Is it a learning exercise or something you're writing for real-world use.

Comment: What's your desired outcome? print the duplicates? print the count of duplicates? How is 5 4 2 3 correct? it's neither the array without duplicates nor their count.

Comment: 5 is appearing 4 times & 2 is appearing 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier technique:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i : array) {
    Integer count = map.get(i);
    if (count == null) {
        map.put(i, 1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(i, count.intValue() + 1);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

For the fun of it, here's a Java 8 equivalent:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i : array) {
    map.compute(i, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);
}

map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
              .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()));
```

The `map.compute()` call could also be replaced by

```
map.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: Easier still, if it's not academic: use `Multiset`.

Comment: @chrylis: agreed. I was about to talk about Guava Multiset, but decided that the OP should learn core Java collections first.

Comment: If Java 8 is available, you could probably replace the last for-loop with a filter lambda function instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement JB Nizet's Java 7 solution. Here is a Java 8 solution:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int[] ints = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0};
    final Map<Integer, Integer> count = IntStream.of(ints).
            boxed().collect(HashMap::new, (map, i) -> {
        map.merge(i, 1, (j, k) -> j + k);
    }, HashMap::putAll);
    //to print out
    count.forEach((i, c) -> {System.out.println( i + " has a count of " + c);});
}
```

Output:

```
0 has a count of 3
1 has a count of 2
2 has a count of 1
3 has a count of 2
4 has a count of 2
5 has a count of 1
6 has a count of 1
7 has a count of 1
8 has a count of 1
9 has a count of 1
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider: see my answer for another, more similar to my original code, Java 8 solution.

Comment: @JBNizet it's the same as mine except you have a loop. My code is more idiomatic if you see what I mean. Also parallelisable - somewhat pointless in this case but worth bearing in mind that looping externally breaks parallel streams.

Comment: Agreed. My aim was to show that the same, intuitive and iterative code could benefit of the new features from Java 8.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, I admit yours is less obtuse. I would prefer `Map.merge` rather than `Map.compute` - means you don't have to handle `null`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my bad, it does compile (I had to download JDK 8 to verify :P). On a side note, while making code parallelisable is good, I think it over-complicates the answer to the original poster's question, for the purpose of just finding duplicates in a simple way.

Comment: @Cupcake that was a slightly facetious comment on my part. The main aim is the idiomatic use of the stream API - just to show how to do things _completely_ differently.

Comment: @Cupcake would you mind deleting the "doesn't compile" comment? Just that it's the first comment on the answer and it might give the wrong impression... Thanks.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: great. I missed the merge() method.

Answer (score 1):

Using indices, create an empty array. Run on your array and increase the corresponding value at the index each time you run on it.

In your example:

```
int[] source = { 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5 };
int[] counts = new int[6];

for (int i : source) {
    counts[i]++;
}
```

Then your can run on the counts and you will get each element (array index) and its count (array value).